# Ресурсы с тестами по Python

Tags: python

В понедельник буду проходить отбор на курсы в компанию на python разработчика, общие знания python есть (написание лаб в универе). Сказали, будет тестирование. Где можно пройти такие тесты?

Comment: Очень любят в яндексе итераторы/генераторы/срезы. На практике, такой магический код вменяемо сопровождать невозможно. )))

Comment: @prospero78su, ваше сообщение не является ответом на вопрос (вообще слабо соотносится с вопросом), поэтому я преобразовал его в комментарий.

По поводу итераторов/генераторов/срезов - вы просто не умеете их готовить.

Comment: Я вполне владею темой вопроса, но сам Великодушный Пожизненный Диктатор по этому поводу высказался недвусмысленно.

И вот вам дзен тру питонёра:

Красивое лучше, чем уродливое.
Явное лучше, чем неявное.
Простое лучше, чем сложное.
Сложное лучше, чем запутанное.
Плоское лучше, чем вложенное.
Разреженное лучше, чем плотное.
Читаемость имеет значение.
Особые случаи не настолько особые, чтобы нарушать правила.

Встретив двусмысленность, отбрось искушение угадать.

Должен существовать один — и, желательно, только один — очевидный способ сделать это.

Если реализацию сложно объяснить — идея плоха.

Comment: @prospero78su, сколько людей - столько и мнений. А Дзен питона можно повернуть так и эдак.

ИМХО итераторы и генераторы - отличнейшая вещь. Это, естественно, не означает, что их нужно использовать в каждой программе. Чем вам не угодили срезы - вообще ума не приложу.

Comment: @prospero78su: 1. BDFL не является автором [`import this`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). Но зато он автор asyncio пакета, который активно поощряет использование генераторов 2. Дзен можно конечно интерпретировать по разному. Но я не вижу где он *"недвусмысленно"* что-то о итераторах/генераторах/срезах говорит. 3. Любым инструментом можно злоупотребить, но итераторы/генераторы/срезы являются одинарными/повседневными/вездесущими средствами языка (Питона). Тяжело себе представить идиоматический Питон-код, который их бы не использовал.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.checkio.org/ - не тест, но достаточно полезный ресурс с задачами на Питон. Советую. Уровень знания языка подтягивается, да и алгоритмы разные тоже знать не помешает.

Answer (score 0):

[CodeAbbey](http://www.codeabbey.com/)

Answer (score 0):

https://certification.mail.ru/ - есть тест по питону, версия 3.4.x без каких-либо доп модулей. Плюс можно сертификат получить.

Answer (score 0):

можно тут http://programarcadegames.com/quiz/progress.php
прикольное обучение и тестирование.